# How to find out which signature verison an APK file has?

Tags: android, apk, digital-signature, android-signing

As you know there is two schemas for signing an APK file.(V1 (Jar Signature) and V2 (Full APK Signature).)

I have an APK file in hand and want to know whether it contains V1 or V2 or both. Is there a CLI tool which I can use it to do so?

Answer (score 3):

The Android SDK tools has a tool called `apksigner` which allows you to verify the signature.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner#options-verify

```
$ apksigner verify --print-certs --verbose app-name.apk
```

You can find the binary under: `[Path to Android SDK]/build-tools/28.0.3/apksigner`

(Replace `28.0.3` which whatever version of build-tools you have)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, but if you can find `apksigner` tool you should go to `$HOME/Android/Sdk/build-tools/<SDK_VERSION>/lib` and run following command with java: 

`java -jar apksigner.jar verify --verbose --print-certs release.apk`

Answer (score 0):

Using [this repository](https://github.com/warren-bank/print-apk-signature) one can easily verify each of apk signatures.

Example:

```
$ ./print-apk-signature kodi-18.3-Leia-arm64-v8a.apk 
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): true
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): false
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: CN=XBMC Foundation, OU=Android platform, O=XBMC Foundation, L=US, ST=US, C=us
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: f517b44b5db5e62a6c1ec55ba47526db7de0d61f6ba26a7987520e293499b8d5
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 5cd9110c3d8e066324615d1279fb93a13c78d666
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: f9f0fe227fadf5c961400472a7e962ca
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 2048
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: 20ab9f102104a30fdf3859fb6b4f4033f7c98f7584530f8aeb46badb5a6bcd97
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: 1b6455e869e679ebb65e0ca4b3cd0ab322e6da44
Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: 441b9aab27029f7a953cd16c2d20f525
```

Comment: I am getting exception : Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: app-release.apk (The system cannot find the file specified)